# Using StyledComponents with CompoundedComponent

Tags: reactjs, antd, styled-components

I'm trying to style something specific about Checkbox (ANTD CompoundedComponent), using the Styled Components

But I'm receiving this error:

[image: Error that I'm receiving]

This is my code:

```
export const StyledCheckbox = styled(Checkbox)`
  ~styles~
`
```

Currently I applied those styles via a global styled components style, but I'm not a fan of this solution. Can someone help me please?

If it helps, here is the Checkbox interface on ANTD:

[image]